# In a Windows batch file, can you chain-execute something that is *not* another batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I understand if you have two `.bat` or `.cmd` files, let's call them `foo` and `bar`, the following rules apply:

Without `call`:

```
:: Welcome to foo.bat
@bar.bat
@echo We never get to this line because bar.bat is "chain-executed".
```

With `call`:

```
:: Welcome to foo.bat
@call bar.bat
@echo This line is executed after bar.bat returns.
```

My question is: is there a way of performing the converse operation, i.e. ensuring that a *non*-batch-file executable *is* chained?

```
:: Welcome to foo.bat
@chain bar.exe
@echo Even though bar is now an .exe,  we never get to this line.
@echo At least, that would be the case if the "chain" command really existed.
```

In other words, is there a way of performing the function of the fictitious `chain` command in that last example?

Comment: Just put bar.exe on a line and it will execute.  When the program exits, it will return to the batch file.

Comment: @Squashman The disadvantage of that would be that `foo.bat`, when double-clicked from Windows explorer, leaves its shell window hanging around while waiting for `bar.exe` to complete.

Comment: Then use the START command.

Comment: Hmm. Actually my comment doesn't make sense: that behaviour also occurs when `bar` is a batch file.  The choice of whether to use `start` or not is I suppose orthogonal to the issue of chaining, and I guess (??) there's no disadvantage to letting execution fall back into `foo` either after `start bar` or just `bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary to use command **start** to run the executable in a separate process and additionally **exit** current batch processing or entire command process.

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to %~nx0
start "Title" bar.exe & exit /B
echo Even though bar is now an .exe, we never get to this line.
```

This batch file starts `bar.exe` in a separate process with `Title` as window title in case of executable is a console application for the new console window opened in this case.

Then after `start` finished `exit /B` is unconditionally executed by command processor while `bar.exe` is running in a separate process resulting in terminating processing of current batch file.

If this batch file was not called itself from another batch file using command **call**, the command processor finishes now processing the batch file resulting in exiting command processing, except the batch file was called with `cmd.exe` with option `/K` to keep command prompt window open after finishing batch processing which is not the case by default.

But if this batch file was called with **call** from another batch file, just processing of this child batch file is finished and command processor continues processing of parent batch file while `bar.exe` runs in a separate process.

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to %~nx0
start "Title" bar.exe & exit
echo Even though bar is now an .exe, we never get to this line.
```

In this batch code the command **exit** is without option `/B` which results in terminating command processing after `start` finished starting `bar.exe` in a separate process even if the current batch file was called from another batch file with **call** and even if batch file processing was started with `cmd.exe` with parameter `/K`.

Instead of unconditionally concatenating the two commands **start** and **exit** with operator `&` it is also possible to use a block as shown below for the two variants.

With just exiting current batch processing:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to %~nx0
(
    start "Title" bar.exe
    exit /B
)
echo Even though bar is now an .exe, we never get to this line.
```

With exiting entire command process:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to %~nx0
(
    start "Title" bar.exe
    exit
)
echo Even though bar is now an .exe, we never get to this line.
```

Such a start of an application with exiting either current batch processing or entire command processing makes of course only sense when `bar.exe` is started depending on at least one condition in the batch file.

Note 1:
It is also possible to use `goto :EOF` instead of `exit /B` to end current batch processing.

Note 2:
`goto :EOF` and `exit /B` result both in just exiting the subroutine if the command is being part of a batch subroutine, i.e. code below a label called with `call :label` because a batch subroutine is just like a child batch file embedded within a main batch file regarding batch processing.

Some more examples to demonstrate the behavior of `call` and `exit /B`:

**Test1.bat**:

```
@echo off
echo Running %~nx0
call Test2.bat
echo Finished %~nx0
```

**Test2.bat**:

```
@echo off
echo Running %~nx0
Test3.bat
echo Finished %~nx0
```

**Test3.bat**:

```
@echo off
echo Finished %~nx0
```

Running `Test1.bat` from within a command prompt window results in output:

```
Running Test1.bat
Running Test2.bat
Finished Test3.bat
Finished Test1.bat
```

So the line `Finished Test2.bat` is missing because command processor returned from `Test3.bat` directly to `Test1.bat`.

Next we compile following C code to console application `Test.exe`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        printf("Running %s with argument %s\n",argv[0],argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Running %s without an argument\n",argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And we make use of `Test.exe` in following 2 batch files:

**Test4.bat**:

```
@echo off
echo Running %~nx0
Test.exe 4
call Test5.bat
echo Finished %~nx0
```

**Test5.bat**:

```
@echo off
echo Running %~nx0
Test.exe 5
Test.exe 6 & exit /B
echo Finished %~nx0
```

Running `Test4.bat` from within a command prompt window results in output:

```
Running Test4.bat
Running Test.exe with argument 4
Running Test5.bat
Running Test.exe with argument 5
Running Test.exe with argument 6
Finished Test4.bat
```

So the line `Finished Test5.bat` is missing because command processor returned from executing `Test.exe` with argument `6` directly to `Test4.bat`.

But with using `bar & exit /B` it is nevertheless important if `bar` is a batch file with file extension `bat` or `cmd`, or an executable with file extension `exe` or `com`. This can be demonstrated by changing code of `Test2.bat` to:

```
@echo off
echo Running %~nx0
Test3.bat & exit /B
echo Finished %~nx0
```

Running `Test1.bat` from within a command prompt window results in output:

```
Running Test1.bat
Running Test2.bat
Finished Test3.bat
```

So with `exit /B` appended in second batch file, command processor interprets **exit** in second batch file as exit in context of first batch file.

Comment: Nice, that taught me something I didn't know regarding `exit` vs `exit /B`.  I guess the behaviour I was looking for is closest to `start bar & exit /B` for non-console processes and `bar & exit /B` for console processes.   The latter has the same apparent behaviour whether `bar` is really `bar.bat` or `bar.exe` (although, under the hood, I think the order of operations differs slightly between the two - hopefully without any gotchas?)

Comment: On using `bar & exit /B` it still matters if `bar` is a batch file or an executable depending on current batch file is just a child batch or a main batch. If `bar & exit /B` is within a batch file not called from a parent batch file with __call__, the processing is the same. But in case of this line is within a __called__ child batch file, the processing is different, see answer above with additional code examples.

Comment: I see, that is a gotcha.  But I guess `bar & goto :eof` doesn't have that problem?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference in batch file processing between `bar & exit /B` and `bar & goto :EOF`. This can be seen by using instead of `exit /B` in above batch files `goto :EOF`. The output (= processing) is always the same.

Comment: I was unable to replicate your assertion that "with `exit /B` appended in second batch file, command processor interprets exit in second batch file as exit in context of first batch file."   I had two files: in `one.cmd` I have `@echo hello 1\n@call two\n@echo goodbye 1` and in `two.cmd` I have `@echo hello 2\n@exit /B\n@echo goodbye 2`. Even though `two` is invoked via `call, the `exit` inside it does not cause `cmd` to exit in the context of `one.cmd` - i.e. I still see "goodbye 1" in the console output.

Comment: Yes, in your example with `one.cmd` __calls__ `two.cmd` the command `exit /B` in `two.cmd` results in just exiting processing of `two.cmd`. But in my example `Test1.bat` __calls__ `Test2.bat` containing the line `Test3.bat & exit /B` __without call__ and therefore continues execution on `Test3.bat`. The `exit /B` in `Test2.bat` is executed after `Test3.bat` finished, but already in context of `Test1.bat` and therefore `Finished Test1.bat` is not output. But `exit /B` in `Test2.bat` would just exit processing of `Test2.bat` if `Test3` would be an EXE instead of a BAT.

Comment: Oh wow. I hadn't quite grasped that one batch file would chain another but *still* execute the second half of the line, after `&`. Thanks for clarification.