# Close command prompt window after batch file execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How to automatically close command prompt window after batch file execution.

I tried command `Start "" & Exit 0` but it's not working.

```
Start ""
@ECHO OFF
C:
cd c:\wamp\www\phpfile
php genCSV.php
"c:\program files\coreftp\coreftp.exe" -s-O -site UPLH -u D:\Files\out\*.*   -p /Import/
del /Q c:\wamp\www\txt\*.*
```

---

### Solution

I used "exit /B" at the of script as per Joey's below answer.

Comment: What do you need the `start ""` for?

Comment: Take a look on answer on [In a Windows batch file, can you chain-execute something that is *not* another batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34231635/3074564) It explains in detail how batch file processing can be exited with or without exiting also command processing, i.e. closing console window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to close even an interactive session, then just use `exit`. Generally though, e.g. from Explorer, batch files are started with `cmd /c` which will close the console after the batch file completes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no text is displayed in the console window to make it close automatically at the end of the batch file. 
Use the EXIT command with the  /B which ends the batch file right then the exit returns to the command window. The clear console will close on certain systems. See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php

You could place this in your Batch file (notice the squiggly after the t in Exit - you most likely will need to use that - but you can try with out it.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.SendKeys "Exit~"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```