# how to execute .bat from within a .bat with different path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm working with multiple .bat files on multiple locations and I would like to connect whole work in one job. So here's the issue:

I have folder called `A A1` and inside there is .bat file which is working with file which is also in the same folder. Then there is folder `A B1` with same setup. Example:

- **W:**

  - **PROJÉČŤ**

    - **A A1**

      - @ START BAT.bat
      - FILE.avi *(which is 60 MB)*

and

- **K:**

  - **PROJÉČŤ**

    - **A B1**

      - @ START BAT.bat
      - FILE.avi *(which is 80 MB)*

Please note the different drives!

So at this point I would like to run `W:\PROJÉČŤ\A A1\@ START BAT.bat` and when this batch file has executed all written commands, I want to automatically start second batch file `K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat` from the first one `W:\PROJÉČŤ\A A1\@ START BAT.bat`

My batch scripts:

**W:\PROJÉČŤ\A A1\@ START BAT.bat**

```
IF EXIST "*.avi" (
    IF NOT EXIST "FILE.avi" (
        REN "*.avi" FILE.avi
    )
    ATTRIB -R "FILE.avi"
    IF EXIST "FILE.avi" (
        ATTRIB -R "FILE.avi"
    )
)
REM ???
PAUSE
EXIT
```

**K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat**

```
IF EXIST "*.avi" (
    IF NOT EXIST "FILE.avi" (
        REN "*.avi" FILE.avi
    )
    ATTRIB -R "FILE.avi"
    IF EXIST "FILE.avi" (
        ATTRIB -R "FILE.avi"
    )
)
PAUSE
EXIT
```

I think I just need to replace the line with `REM ???` with a command like

```
START "K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"
```

But the listed commands below have unfortunately not worked:

```
START "K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"
CALL "K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"
START CALL "K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"
START cmd /K CALL"K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"
```

The batch file in directory `K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1` was not executed from within batch file in directory `W:\PROJÉČŤ\A A1`.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not name a batch file like an internal command of Windows command processor or a standard Windows console application stored in `system32` directory of Windows. `@ START BAT.bat` is definitely not a good name for a batch file because it contains command `start`, has spaces in file name and `@` is also very unusual in file names which is the reason why this character was selected many years ago as separator in email addresses.

---

The task renaming (hopefully) one AVI file not named `FILE.avi` to `FILE.avi` in each subfolder of `"W:\PROJÉČŤ` and `"K:\PROJÉČŤ` and remove read-only attribute can be done with the following batch code saved into `AviFileRename.bat`:

```
@echo off
call :AviFileRename "W:\PROJÉČŤ"
call :AviFileRename "K:\PROJÉČŤ"
goto :EOF

:AviFileRename
for /R %1 %%# in (*.avi) do (
    if /I "%%~n#" == "FILE" (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -r "%%#"
    ) else (
        ren "%%#" "FILE.avi"
        %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -r "%%~dp#FILE.avi"
    )
)
```

It does not matter in which directory `AviFileRename.bat` is saved with those code lines.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `attrib /?`
- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`

---

Command **call** can be used usually to continue processing of a main batch on a sub-batch, and when processing this sub-batch finished, continue processing of main batch. For details see answer on [How to call a batch file in the parent folder of current batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564)

But command **exit** without option `/B` results in exiting entire command process, not just processing of current batch file. For details see answer on [In a Windows batch file, can you chain-execute something that is *not* another batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34231635/3074564) And read the help output on running in a command prompt window `exit /?`. The solution is using command **start** to run the batch file in a new command process.

But just using

```
START "K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"
```

is not enough because

1. command **start** interprets first string in double quotes as optional title - run in a command prompt window `start /?` for details;
2. the current directory is not set to the directory of the started batch file as required for the lines in `@ START BAT.bat` in `K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1`.

A working command line would be:

```
start "Processing A B1" /D"K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1" "K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"
```

This command put into `W:\PROJÉČŤ\A A1\@ START BAT.bat` instead of line with command **REM** would work.

Explanation of the parameters, please refer to output of `start /?`:

1. `"Processing A B1"` ... title for the new process window. Could be also an empty string specified with `""`. But something readable for a human as window title is always better than a console window with no title. A title string is required if any other parameter is specified on the command line with double quotes.
2. `/D"K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1"` ... defines the working directory for the new command process.
3. `"K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"` ... the command / executable / script to start is in this case the batch file `@ START BAT.bat` in directory `K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1`.

You may want to add additionally the **start** parameter `/wait` after `/D"K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1"` to run the batch file in the new command process and halt processing of `W:\PROJÉČŤ\A A1\@ START BAT.bat` always until started batch file finished and command process was exited by command **exit** or when last line of batch file was processed by command processor.

---

But there is one more problem with folder name `PROJÉČŤ`. It contains the non ASCII characters `ÉČŤ` and therefore it is important that in text editor used for editing the batch file the correct code page is set as otherwise directory `PROJÉČŤ` would not be found. The code page in a console window depends on Windows region and language settings.

Running in a command prompt window **chcp** displays the code page defined for command processes on your machine. This (usually) **OEM** code page must be used also in text editor and not the ANSI (Windows) code page usually used by text editor for editing text files.

Comment: Well, I've read whole `start /?` and I still can't tell where's `"Processing <folder>"` comes from. Is that some kind of unmentioned subcommand?

Comment: The __title__ string is optional. But __start__ interprets first double quoted string always as title string and therefore it is often required to define explicitly a title string. Run from within a command prompt window `start "K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat"` and you can watch that instead of running this batch file, just a new console window opens with title `K:\PROJÉČŤ\A B1\@ START BAT.bat`. That's the reason for the title string `"Processing A B1"` which can be also `""` or `"Judge Dredd"`.

Comment: thank you! your suggestion of abandoning "@" character, using `CHCP 1250 > NUL 2>&1` and `START "<title>" /D"<folder>" /WAIT "<path>" /ABOVENORMAL` solved my issue

Comment: just wondering, what would I need to do to execute batch that is in subfolder? tried: `START "subfolder name is AA" /D"AA" /WAIT "AA\start bat.bat"` but with no luck

Comment: The current directory is with `/D"AA"` the subfolder `AA` for new command process. Starting from this folder now `"AA\start bat.bat"` in new command process will not work as there is most likely no more subfolder `AA` within current folder `AA`. You need: `START "subfolder name is AA" /D"AA" /WAIT "start bat.bat"`. The batch file is either referenced with full path or with path relative to directory set as working directory for new command process.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to have spaces in your file name, and @ is not a character that needs escaping.  That said, it is much easier sometimes to name your batch files without special characters or spaces and use dashes between words like `my-cool-script.bat`.

Here is an example that should mimic what you are doing that should help you debug your scripts.

```
Directory of L:\test

12/27/2015  11:12 AM    <DIR>          .
12/27/2015  11:12 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/27/2015  11:12 AM               118 @ start one.bat
12/27/2015  11:08 AM                56 @ start two.bat

L:\test>"@ start one.bat"
ONE
Running "@ start one.bat"
Calling @ start two.bat
TWO
Running "L:\test\@ start two.bat"
Bye from "L:\test\@ start two.bat"
Bye from "@ start one.bat"
```

And here are contents of the batch files:

```
L:\test>type *.bat

@ start one.bat


@echo off
echo ONE
echo Running %0
echo Calling @ start two.bat
call "L:\test\@ start two.bat"
echo Bye from %0

@ start two.bat


@echo off
echo TWO
echo Running %0
echo Bye from %0
```

This also works if the files are in different directories:

```
Directory of L:\test

12/27/2015  11:35 AM    <DIR>          one
12/27/2015  11:35 AM    <DIR>          two

Directory of L:\test\one

12/27/2015  11:35 AM               116 @ start one.bat

Directory of L:\test\two

12/27/2015  11:35 AM                54 @ start two.bat

L:\test>"one\@ start one.bat"
ONE
Running "one\@ start one.bat"
Calling @ start two.bat
TWO
Running "L:\test\two\@ start two.bat"
Bye from "L:\test\two\@ start two.bat"
Bye from "one\@ start one.bat"
```

And the updated contents of the first bat file:

```
L:\test>type "one\@ start one.bat"
@echo off
echo ONE
echo Running %0
echo Calling @ start two.bat
call "L:\test\two\@ start two.bat"
echo Bye from %0
```

Another update to show how to reference the current directory of the script and not just "current directory" of where the script started.

`%~dp0` is the key here...

```
L:\test>dir /s
Directory of L:\test
12/27/2015  03:12 PM    <DIR>          one
12/27/2015  03:12 PM    <DIR>          two

Directory of L:\test\one
12/27/2015  03:17 PM               170 @ start one.bat
12/27/2015  03:12 PM                 8 file.txt

Directory of L:\test\two
12/27/2015  03:17 PM               104 @ start two.bat
12/27/2015  03:12 PM                13 file.txt
```

ONE

```
@echo off
echo ONE
echo Running %0
echo From Directory: %~dp0
echo Calling @ start two.bat
dir "%~dp0\file.txt"
call "L:\test\two\@ start two.bat"
echo Bye from %0
```

TWO

```
@echo off
echo TWO
echo Running %0
echo From Directory: %~dp0
dir "%~dp0\file.txt"
echo Bye from %0
```

OUTPUT

```
L:\test>"one\@ start one.bat"
ONE
Running "one\@ start one.bat"
From Directory: L:\test\one\
Calling @ start two.bat

Directory of L:\test\one

12/27/2015  03:12 PM                 8 file.txt
           1 File(s)              8 bytes

TWO
Running "L:\test\two\@ start two.bat"
From Directory: L:\test\two\

Directory of L:\test\two

12/27/2015  03:12 PM                13 file.txt
           1 File(s)             13 bytes
Bye from "L:\test\two\@ start two.bat"
Bye from "one\@ start one.bat"

L:\test>
```

You should have all you need to fix your scripts.

Comment: well what you described is "running two bats from same folder/location" so... not really my case tho

Comment: I updated my example to 2 different directories, and `call "L:\test\two\@ start two.bat"` or `call "W:\test\two\@ start two.bat"` will work the same.  Have you tried to run my examples on your machine to solve the original question you asked about how to call a 2nd script from the 1st one?

Comment: yeah I tried out your example but it's not what I seek for because that 2nd bat is executed trought first bat instead new separate execution. in your example I would work with FILE.avi (which is 60mb) and then it would autostart 2nd batch which would work also with FILE.avi (which is 60mb) instead of FILE.avi (which is 80mb)

Comment: OK, that was not your original question, but I see that was the problem you might have been trying to solve.  I will update to my answer to show you how to use variable modifiers to ensure you are using a path to your files instead of just "file.txt".  `for /?` has good examples of how to use these.